# Vim regex search history not working as expected

Tags: vim

When using the regex search in Vim, I always had the option to press the up and down arrows to cycle through all of the recent searches I made on that particular file. For some reason, now when I press the up arrow, I see the letter A, and the letter B for when I press down. I haven't changed my .vimrc or anything. Is there some option that I may have accidentally toggled on that would be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `compatible` is not set.

```
set nocomaptible
```

Also make sure your terminal settings are correct. (When you use the arrow keys in normal mode, do they work, or do you get weird behavior?)